# Pandas - sortlevel() appears not to be lexicographical

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I am attempting to sort a multiindexed (index and columns) dataframe by index level and am getting unexpected results.  Here is my dataframe prior to the sortlevel call:

[Dataframe prior to sortlevel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqVt9.png)

[image]

I then call sortlevel as follows:

```
test.sortlevel(level='Bins',inplace=True,ascending=False)
```

This returns the following dataframe:

[Dataframe after sortlevel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5NQE.png)

[image]
I expect the order to be Excellent, Good, Mediocre, Non Competitive, Score. An examination of the index levels via:

```
print test.index.levels
```

returns the following list:

```
[[...,u'fch_rf_5_off',...],[u'Non Competitive', u'Mediocre', u'Good', u'Excellent', u'Score']]
```

This list doesn't show any characters before 'Score' that might cause this. I'm at a loss for ideas and appreaciate any help!